# Audit total no. of records inserted based on latest insert date using oracle trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I need to write a trigger that will find the total no. of records inserted based on the latest insert date.

I have tried using the statement level(**after insert**) trigger, but it's not giving me the expected output?

```
create or replace trigger trig
after insert on base_table
declare
  v_cnt:=0;
begin

select count(*) into v_cnt  from base_table where ins_date= ( select max(ins_date) from base_table);
  insert into audit_table values(v_cnt,sysdate);
  commit;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your trigger is invalid (`v_cnt` doesn't have a datatype; you can't `commit` in a trigger (unless it is an autonomous transaction)) so I doubt it would produce *any* result. And what *is* expected result?

---

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table base_table (id number, ins_date date);

Table created.

SQL> create table audit_table (cnt number, datum date);

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trig
  2    after insert on base_table
  3  declare
  4    v_cnt number := 0;
  5  begin
  6    select count(*)
  7    into v_cnt
  8    from base_table
  9    where ins_date = (select max(ins_date) from base_table);
 10
 11    insert into audit_table values (v_cnt, sysdate);
 12  end;
 13  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into base_table (id, ins_date)
  2  select level, sysdate from dual connect by level <= 3;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * From base_table;

        ID INS_DATE
---------- ----------
         1 21.10.2021
         2 21.10.2021
         3 21.10.2021

SQL> select * from audit_table;

       CNT DATUM
---------- ----------
         3 21.10.2021

SQL>
```

That *looks* OK to me. Perhaps, you meant to use `TRUNC`

```
select max(trunc(ins_date)) from base_table
```

in a subquery, if `ins_date` contains time component.